# Why is ant d wrapping a text in acnchor tag in the dropdowns of its table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am fairly new to ant d library. So far Im happing with the ease it is providing. I just couldn't understand as it is not mentioned in the documentation that why does ant d wraps any text or image inside dropdown with an anchor tag

So far, in almost every example I could see a code like this

```
    return (
      <Dropdown
        overlay={menu}
        onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
        visible={this.state.visible}
      >
        // why wrapping in anchor tag?
        <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
          Hover me
        </a>
      </Dropdown>
    );
```

Also I found If I dont use anchor tag. the dropdown only appears If I hover excatly on top of this text or if its a menu img in place of text.

Here Im just trying to understand the nesting of the tags because in my understanding its not a link and we shouldn't use anchor tag when not needed and our design and hierarchy of nodes should be logical and understandable. Or maybe Im missing something here. Anyone?

Here are the links to the documentation
[Table](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-colspan-rowspan)
[Dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/#)

Answer (score 0):

Antd's Dropdown by definition expects to receive a single React child element, so you can wrap the text inside with whatever jsx tag you want (say a `span`). See this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-pine-mlod5

You can also use `Dropdown.Button` but that creates a different layout.